# Unable to install neo4j 3.3.6/3.4.4 community version in windows

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

```
c:\Users\raviteja\Desktop\neo4j-community-3.3.6-windows\neo4j-community-3.3.6\bin>neo4j install-service

c:\Users\raviteja\Desktop\neo4j-community-3.3.6-windows\neo4j-community-3.3.6\bin>net start neo4j

System error 2 has occurred.

The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried the same process for both 3.3.6 and 3.4.4 versions but has the same result
I have the required files installed before I have started installing neo4j

Answer (score 0):

Well I have cleared my question on my  research.
To start a neo4j browser in windows you have to click following command

```
User>neo>neo>bin>neo4j console
```

then get into localhost:7474/browser/

And to type in neo4j console use the following command

```
User>neo>neo>bin>cypher-shell
```

You are now into neo4j console to develo your srcipt
Note: You can't do multi lining in windows